# How to stop iteration when if statement is true?

Tags: python, iteration

I'm having some troubles with stopping iteration in Python. This problem occurs in function:

```
for z in range(w.steps):
    for i in range(1,w.x-1):
        for j in range(1,w.y-1):
            print (i, j)
            for r in data.c:
                if w.world[i][j] in r:
                    print r
                    ind = data.c.index(r)
                    print ind
                    if w.world[i-1][j] in data.n[ind]:
                        if w.world[i][j+1] in data.e[ind]:
                            if w.world[i+1][j] in data.s[ind]:
                                if w.world[i][j-1] in data.w[ind]:
                                    w.world[i][j] = data.cc[ind]
```

Number of steps (first `for` loop) is provided by user. Next two `for` loops are for iterating through two - dimensional array(`x`-rows, `y`-cols):

```
for i in range(1,w.x-1):
    for j in range(1,w.y-1):
```

(prints are only for control)
For each cell in array I wanto to check its value. I have all possible values(let's say value=14) in data.c list, which looks like that one:

```
li = [[2],[14,23],[4]]
```

So the instruction:

```
for r in data.c:
    if w.world[i][j] in r:
```

I want to stop iterating when first `true` will appear. If function will hit first equal value, I want to assign index of list which contains it, and do other statements:

```
ind = data.c.index(r)
    if w.world[i-1][j] in data.n[ind]:
        if w.world[i][j+1] in data.e[ind]:
            if w.world[i+1][j] in data.s[ind]:
                if w.world[i][j-1] in data.w[ind]:
                    w.world[i][j] = data.cc[ind]
```

If all of them are `true`, I want to execute last instruction (assignment), and go to next cell from array. But if at least one of them is `false`, I want to go back, and seek for next hit in `data.c` list (there could be much more than one). There are for sure in the lists values for all possibilities. The point is to use first which will match.

I tried this function for 1 cell, and I get much more indexes than expected and I don't know why. Output for one cell from array with my comments which is what:

```
(1, 1)     # print(i,j)
[0]        # print r
3          # print data.c.index(r)
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
[0]
3
```

I will be very thankful for any help since I'm dealing with this algorithm for a long time (I'm a beginner in programming).

Comment: A good rule of thumb: If you need 9 levels of indentation, consider to refactor your code.

Comment: I'd really advise you to look for some Python book (really - any book) and read it. Read through all of it. Learning through examples without knowing even half of the grammar constructs can be really painful. And pointless really. That was how I was introduced to my first language - Pascal, and I think I lost a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for all advices, I will refactor my code.

I know that the best way is to read whole book first, but the fact is that we have some projects to do for classes and sometimes unfortunately there is no time to read through all of it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you need to place a `break` statement.

```
for z in range(w.steps):
    for i in range(1,w.x-1):
        for j in range(1,w.y-1):
            print (i, j)
            for r in data.c:
                if w.world[i][j] in r:
                    print r
                    ind = data.c.index(r)
                    print ind
                    if w.world[i-1][j] in data.n[ind]:
                        if w.world[i][j+1] in data.e[ind]:
                            if w.world[i+1][j] in data.s[ind]:
                                if w.world[i][j-1] in data.w[ind]:
                                    w.world[i][j] = data.cc[ind]
                                    break # <-- break "for r" and continue with "for j"
```

Comment: It's doing the same as described in comment below.

Comment: @Mateusz: examine your algorithm step by step on a paper with a small data sample. There might be a logical error in the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (z,i,j) in itertools.product(range(w.steps), range(1,w.x-1)), range(1,w.y-1)):
        for r in data.c:
            if w.world[i][j] in r :
                ind = data.c.index(r)
                if all (itertools.imap(lambda x, y: x in y, 
                                    (w.world[i-1][j], w.world[i][j+1],w.world[i+1][j], w.world[i][j-1]), 
                                    (data.n[ind], data.e[ind], data.s[ind], data.w[ind]))):
                    w.world[i][j] = data.cc[ind]
                    break
```

Comment: I've tried to use your code, but when I've put `print(i,j)` and `print r` as well as `print ind` just after first if statement I've received the same output as one from question (above). Even if other `if` statements are false (or even one of them) it should check next one from `data.c` so index should be different.